# Excel 2010, using named list based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm not the strongest in Execel, I was wondering how to populated a named list (dropdown) based on value in another cell. Here is my example, column A contains countries, column B I wanted populate with the states based on the country value. then in column C (hidden cell) put the state code of the selected state from column B.  I hope that makes sense.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
=IF($F$5="Corporate Affairs and Records", CorporateAffairs,
IF($F$5="Dealer/Customer Credit", DealerCustomerCredit,
IF($F$5="Engineering", Engineering,IF$F$5="Environmental", Environmental,
IF$F$5="Finance/Banking and Investments", BankingAndInvestments,
IF$F$5="Finance/General Ledger", GeneralLedger, 
IF$F$5="Finance/Accounts Payable", AccountsPayable, 
IF$F$5="Finance/Accounts Receivable", AccountsReceivable, 
IF$F$5="Finance/Tax", Tax, 
IF$F$5="Organization and Records Management", OrganizationAndRecords, 
IF$F$5="Payroll", Payroll, 
IF$F$5="Personnel/Industrial Relations", Personnel, 
IF$F$5="Production", Production, 
IF$F$5="Purchasing", Purchasing, 
IF$F$5="Risk Management", RiskManagement, 
IF$F$5="Sales, Leasing and Marketing", Sales,
IF$F$5="Warranty/Field Service", Warranty)))))))))))))))))
```

running into size limitation in the source text box of the data validation.

Comment: Have you considered some sort of Excel Tutorial?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question.  i know how to create a named range, that's easy.  i guess i really don't know how to do the conditional piece.  Mitch, i guess i'm not understanding the point of this site.  I thought it was to seek guidance when you're stuck.

Comment: you haven't supplied any code or evidence of your attempt. BTW, not my downvote.

Comment: the problem i'm running into is there appears to be a size limit on the source of the data validation and don't know how to get around it.  does that make sense?  please don't pay to much attention to the syntax.  i had to delete some If statement to allow it to fit space allowed.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14996838/1953175

Answer (score 1):

One way:

Create a lookup table relating all the possible F5 values (col1) to your range names (col2) and name the table range (eg) "LOOKUPS"

For your validation list source you can then use something like:

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($F$5,LOOKUPS,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: didn't think that vlookup could handle multiple rows matches my col1 value though?  i just tried it and that's the error i'm getting.

Comment: You're going to need to create a new question if you're still having problems.  My suggestion was based on your example formula.